# How to properly install NVIDIA RTX drivers in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: nvidia, laptop, cuda, gpu

I have bought a gaming laptop with GPU RTX 3050 mobile.
And since I want to use it for machine learning and deep learning stuff, I want to make sure that I've proper access to its graphics card.

Till now, I've tried :

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

And then :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

and it gave me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 432, in autoinstall
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to edit detect.py
Commands

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py
```

Then scroll to line 835.

Change that line of code to

```
version = int(package_name.split('-')[-2])
```

Save and close your file. You may also want to reboot.

Apparently, it is a bug because some drivers ends with a word instead of an integer. Ec. driver-name-525-open. This code adjustment takes the 525 integer value.

Comment: Or just use the non "-open" version of the driver.